# No me coge la funcion javascript en jquery de un JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un archivo js que contiene esta función:

```
function Relleno(variable){
      if(variable!=""){
    return true
}
else{
    return false;
}

}
```

Luego tengo un JSP donde uso esta función en mi Jquery

```
<script src="../js/funciones.js"></script>
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 var nombre = "";
 if(Relleno(nombre)){
    alert("Esta relleno");
 }
 else{
    alert("Vacio");
 }

</script>
```

Y cuando pruebo no me saca ningún alert.
La ruta me parece que sí que está bien. Llamo a funciones.js desde Productos.jsp, adjunto imagén.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que te falta subir una carpeta más. <script src="../../js/funciones.js"></script>

Comment: parece que tampoco es por eso :S

Comment: Fijate en la consola del browser si tira algún error, por ejemplo que no encuentra el script, o que el mismo tiene un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Por la estructura me parece que esta linea <script src="../js/funciones.js"></script> debería ser <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>

Comment: También te conviene cargar primero el script de jQuery y después el de funciones.js. Si funciones usa jQuery te va a dar un error.

Comment: En la consola pone que ha fallado la carga del script, el de funciones solo tiene esa función de momento

Comment: Por lo que he leído recomiendan meter los recursos en la carpeta WEB-INF para poder acceder a ellos. Pero a una mala, <script src="./js/funciones.js"></script> este escript debería buscar una carpeta llamada js que tenga dentro un archivo funciones.js.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="<c:url value = "js/funciones.js"/>"></script>
```

prueba este, y tu carpeta `contenedores` deberia estar dentro del `WEB-INF`, generalmente suele pasar por esta fuera de contexo

Comment: ¿además de contenedores, el js y el css también?

Comment: NO, esos son considerados estaticos, si quieres puedes juntar en una carpeta `static` los `JS, CSS, IMG` y no necesitas `../` es decir subir de nivel, para todos los que no lleven `.jsp`,

Comment: he metido los contenedores en web-inf y cuando arranco el productos.jsp me sale un error 404.¿sabes el motivo?

Comment: en el `return` debes especificar `contenedores/lproductos`

Comment: perdona, es que soy novato todavía en esto, ¿el return donde le coloco?

Comment: OK, Subire la Solucion en un nuevo Comentario, que acabo de ejecutar

Comment: vale muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Publicar la solucion es bastante larga, asi que tu carpeta `Contenedores` dejalo al nivel de `index` es decir fuera de la carpeta `WEB-INF` e importa de esta forma tus scripts `<script src="js/funciones.js"></script>` directo a la carpeta de archivos sin los `../` incluso tus `contenedores`
`<a href="contenedores/Productos.jsp">Productos</a>` suficiente para el `Hola Mundo` e importar primero el `jquery`

El `return` es un concepto de `servlet` y malabares con los `XML` de configuracion, te recomiendo marcar la casilla de `Spring Framework` a la hora de crear un `Nuevo Proyecto`, este ordena y configura todo por ti

Comment: lo primero lo tengo ya tal cual, pero la segunda parte, yo no uso spring. Pero con la primera parte sigue sin irme... :S

Comment: y bueno con el css me pasa lo mismo, al ser archivos externos no me los coge...

Comment: te pasaré el archivo de la solucion larga https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GgHK738JOUqgBaCSJq61Nehn_cW7UVZx